# How to pass profile while using aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4 in github actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions

I'm trying to configure aws credentials on my Github actions **ubuntu-latest runner**.

```
name: AWS Login

on:
  push:
    branches: "dev"

jobs:
  Deploy:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./Infrastructure
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: dev

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: **aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4**
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
          aws-region: us-west-2
          #profile : "my-profile"
```

Here the catch is this aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials does not accept any input as profile or any parameter to configure the profile.

How can i achieve it?

I have a work-around here

```
#!/bin/bash
aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE  set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE  set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
aws configure --profile $AWS_PROFILE  set region $AWS_REGION
aws configure list
```

But i want to know if there's a way to achieve same with this aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials?

Comment: Do you actually _need_ multiple profiles within the same job?

Comment: No, I need only single profile.